# Capybara - verifying a piece of JS is executed

Tags: rspec

Is there a way with Capybara to verify a piece of JS is executed?

I have in a Rails app a remote action and after submitting a form I'd like to make sure the following code is executed

```
$('#area').html("<%= j(render partial:'area') %>");
```

I understand I could verify the page has the partial content, but if possible I'd rather not couple the spec with the markup.

Thanks.